# XSLT - Sorting a portion of an xml is deleting other fields

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to sort a portion of an xml.

The Structure is

```
queryCompoundEmployeeResponse  
CompoundEmployee  
Person  
  fields...fields  
  fields...fields  
  fields...fields  
  EmploymentInformation  
    fields...fields  
    fields...fields  
          job_information  
          date...date  
          job_information  
          date...date
```

All I need to sort is job_information under employment_information.under job_information is a field called end_date.

The problem is that the fields under employment_information (which is on the same level as job_information is deleted from the output.

Here is the xslt program

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="employment_information">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="job_information">
      <!--  concat year, month, day -->
        <xsl:sort select="concat(
                  substring(end_date, 1, 4),
                  substring(end_date, 6, 2),
                  substring(end_date, 9, 2)

                  )" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample input XML? The reason the siblings of `job_information` under `employee_information` are deleted is because those templates are not applied. Since you are modifying the `employee_information` template, you need to apply the child templates from the original input XML.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the term "deleted" suggests a misunderstanding about how XSLT works. An XSLT stylesheet constructs a result tree by copying or transforming selected information from the source tree. If there's part of the source tree that your stylesheet ignores, then it won't be present in the result tree. It's not that it's been deleted, it's that you haven't done anything that would cause it to be copied.

In your template for `employmentInformation`, you are copying/transforming the `jobInformation` children, and ignoring everything else. If you want the other children to be represented in the output, then you need to do something with them, for example by `xsl:apply-templates` or by `xsl:copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I was able to solve this.

```
    enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="employment_information">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::job_information)]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[self::job_information]">
      <!--  concat year, month, day -->
        <xsl:sort select="concat(
                  substring(end_date, 1, 4),
                  substring(end_date, 6, 2),
                  substring(end_date, 9, 2)

                  )" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **1.** `select="*[self::job_information]"` is a very elaborate way to say `select="job_information"`. -- **2.** You can sort by `end_date` as it is - there is no reason to extract the components and put them back together in the same order.